# Mixing n lists of size m to create a matrix (m*m*m*..n times) in Python 3

Tags: list, numpy-ndarray, python-3.8

Need to create a "matrix" from 'n' lists where indices are mixed such that each list contributes an element to the matrix recursively. Using the typical mathematical notation where M is the matrix variable and list'n' are n lists, I want such that

```
M[i][j][k]... = list1[i]list2[j]list3[k]...
```

I know how to do it by nesting `for` loops but can not do it for an arbitrary number of lists.

```
for i in range(len(list1)):
    for j in range(len(list2)):
        ...
            ...
```

Edit : E.g. if I have

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [0,7,8]
list3 = [4,5,6]
```

then I want to create a 'matrix' M (numpy array) such that

```
M[1,1,1] = (1,0,4)
M[1,2,3] = (1,7,6)
M[3,1,2] = (3,0,5)
```

In total this matrix will have 27 elements with a 3X3X3 structure.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're trying to do. Could you give an example?
From what I can tell, you're stuck at determining n.
To calculate n:

```
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [0,7,8]
list3 = [4,5,6]


lsts = [item for item in dir() if 'list' in item]
n = len(lsts)
print(n)
```

dir() are the variables in your python file up until that point.

EDIT:
Your example does not make sense.
matrix[1,1,1] refers to a single value in the matrix (really, a tensor since it's 3-d, matrices are 2-d). You have matrix[1,1,1] equal to 3 values. It should be equal to a single value. You could have each value be be equal to a vector but then your matrix (really, tensor) would have another, 4th dimension, making your tensor 3x3x3x3.

Also in Python the 1st value is denoted with zero. For example, list1[0] = 1, list2[0] = 0, list3[0] = 4, list1[1] = 2, etc.